# Is it possible for Dialogflow to be linked to a search engine like google?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to have a function where when the user asks a question such as "Where is Singapore? " or "When is the next Maroon 5 concert?" and for the results to be given to the user. 
I'm using the inline-editor.
I saw another question were they said it was possible, but am still not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with prebuilt agents.

You can see the documentation here: https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents/prebuilt-smalltalk

You can add prebuilt agents to your project by looking at the prebuilt agents tab in the console (http://console.dialogflow.com)